# Getting link to abstract indexed in Google Scholar

Tags: google, google-index

We have a large digital library with thousands of papers indexed in Google Scholar. We allow Google Scholar to index our PDFs but they're blocked unless you have a subscription. So Google has full-text indexing/searching of our PDFs (great!) but then the links point just to those PDFs (boo!) instead of the more helpful abstract pages.

Does anyone know what could cause an issue like this? I am, to the best of my knowledge, following all of the guidelines laid out in their [Inclusion Guidelines](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html).

Here's some example meta data:

```
<meta name="citation_title" content="Sample Title"/>
<meta name="citation_author" content="LastName, FirstName"/>
<meta name="citation_publication_date" content="2012/06/26"/>
<meta name="citation_volume" content="1"/>
<meta name="citation_issue" content="1"/>
<meta name="citation_firstpage" content="10"/>
<meta name="citation_lastpage" content="20"/>
<meta name="citation_conference_title" content="Name of the Conference"/>
<meta name="citation_isbn" content="1-234567-89-X"/>
<meta name="citation_pdf_url" content="http://www.example.org/p/1234/proceeding_1234.pdf"/>
<meta name="citation_fulltext_html_url" content="http://www.example.org/f/1234/"/>
<meta name="citation_abstract_html_url" content="http://www.example.org/p/1234/"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.org/p/1234/" />
```

`example.org/p/1234` is the abstract page for the article; `example.org/f/1234` is the fulltext link accessible to subscribers only (and to Google Scholar). `example.org/p/1234/proceeding_1234.pdf` is the fulltext PDF link.

Answer (score 1):

That canonical URL you have could be causing the issue. That canonical should not be on the abstract URLs or else Google will use it instead for its indexes.

Also ensure that *robots.txt* is not blocking your `citation_fulltext_html_url` path or `citation_abstract_html_url` path.

Minor, and probably not an issue but you have no space after the quotations. Example `name="citation_pdf_url"content="` I would add a spaces just to be sure to help the parser like so `name="citation_pdf_url" content="`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The canonical URL is the URL for the abstract page. I want Google to use it.

Comment: Oh fiddlesticks, just realized that the links for abstract and full text are wrong in the example code. That's why you said what you did.

Comment: The canonical tag on a page will make that url the link in the index regardless of anything else. In other words if you have canonical = /p/1234/  on the page /f/1234/ then never will f/1234 be in google index. period. Remove the canonical in your situation because you want google to handle them all seperately. You can watch a few videos on these topics at http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp/videos?query=canonical

Comment: Also Google's Maile Ohye touches on some of the negatives of the canonical tag in this rel prev/next video (not quite the same but you'll get the idea of when not to use rel canonical and how it works) http://youtu.be/njn8uXTWiGg

Comment: I put different canonical links on each page. So when you go to /f/1234, the canonical link is /f/1234. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am not sure why your using canonical tag in your situation. I looked at other Google scholar results and none of them use canonical tag in the headers of their abstract or fulltext pages. It's been some time, have you made any changes to your headers? Has Google indexed anything differently?  Have you added a sitemap.xml?

Comment: I'm using a canonical because the pages are also indexed Google and used to be query params based (i.e. `/?paper_id=12345&action=ViewAbstract` which simply became `/p/12345`. I want Google to know that anytime it arrives at one of the old-style pages, it should replace that in its index with the new URL format).

Comment: In addition, Google has not problem indexing the site normally, which is what `sitemap.xml` is for. It only seems to do this for Google Scholar.

Comment: I'm like 99.99% sure that the canonical url tag is not the problem. Not sure why you're so focused on it.

Comment: I'm concerned about it because having the canonical tag shown incorrectly or in the wrong place or case can have negative effects like telling Google 'ignore this page' and 'don't index this' etc. In any case now that your telling me about the parameters, you should be permanent 301 redirecting those to the right place using something like modrewrite.